# how to keep the order of keys when when an object pushed to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object as below

```
var obj = { el: 'el', app: 'app'};
var arr = [];
// pushed obj to arr array
arr.push(obj);
```

When I looked at the console, `arr[0]` has the obj with sorted keys such as `{app: 'app', el:'el'}`.

My requirement here is to keep the order same.

How can I keep the order same?

Comment: objects have no concept of key "order" ... because the "order" is irrelevant ... you'll find though, that when you process the object with `for ... in` or `Object.keys` - the order the keys will be processed is that in which the keys were defined ... in this case, `el` then `app` - don't take console.log output to be anything other than informative

Comment: Note: `the order the keys will be processed is that in which the keys were defined` - this is the case in Firefox, but it's actually not a requirement of any specification ... the specification actually doesn't state what order `for ... in` should return keys ... I've read that `Object.keys` will return keys in the same order as `for ... in` - but again, I don't think that's a specified requirement of the language

Comment: out of interest, what happens if you `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[0]))`

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX, JSON.stringify() shows correct order. 
As you said console.log output is just for information purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var obj = { el: 'el', app: 'app' };
            var arr = [];
            jQuery.each( obj, function ( i, val )
            {
                arr.push( obj[i] );
            } );
```

Comment: that would push each value on to the array separately - without any reference to the key - please read the question again